# How to make otf fonts work on Azure on a pure angular site

Tags: angularjs, azure, web, fonts, web-config

I have a pure angular website (not .Net) that I want to host on Azure. I uploaded necessary files my Azure folder over FTP. Site works fine except fonts. It cannot load .otf fonts. Since my website is not .Net, it doesn't even have a web.config file. So I created the following web.config file to be able to support .otf file type:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>

    </configSections>
    <system.web>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
         </staticContent>   
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

After this, I started to get the following error message:

```
The configuration section 'staticContent' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration.
```

I tried to declare it in the `<configSections>` part like this:

```
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer" type="System.WebServer.Configuration.SystemWebServerSectionGroup">
        <section name="staticContent" type="System.WebServer.Configuration.StaticContentSection" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
    </sectionGroup>
```

And now I get the following error:

```
There is a duplicate 'system.webServer/staticContent' section defined
```

So if I don't declare the section, it doesn't work. If I declare it, then it is duplicate. Am I missing something or is Azure kidding with me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried to put in your webconfig: ... be carefully..it's in the  `<system.webServer>` section

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/otf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />

    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I cannot believe that I wrote "system.web" instead of system.webServer. So it was just a typo. I will go and wash my face. Thank you federico! I only added otf declaration though.